# How to Set Log Level for Third Party Jar in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, kinetica

I use Spark to write data from Hive Table to Kinetica using this jar: `kinetica-spark-7.0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. However, when I run `spark-submit`, the logger from the jar is printing the JDBC connection string with its credentials as follows:

```
...
22/03/03 03:00:58 INFO spark.LoaderParams: Using JDBC connection string: jdbc:kinetica://10.xx.xx.xx:9191;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx
22/03/03 03:00:58 INFO spark.LoaderParams: Installing truststore to bypass certificate check.
22/03/03 03:00:58 INFO spark.LoaderParams: Using URL(s) http://10.xx.xx.xx:9191to create a GPUdb connection
22/03/03 03:00:59 INFO spark.LoaderParams: Connecting to http://10.xx.xx.xx:9191 as user <xxx>
22/03/03 03:00:59 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 47
22/03/03 03:00:59 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 42
22/03/03 03:00:59 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 53
22/03/03 03:00:59 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 52
...
```

which is coming from this piece of code: [kinetica.spark.LoaderParams](https://github.com/kineticadb/kinetica-connector-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/kinetica/spark/LoaderParams.scala#L227)

I want to set the log level specifically for this `spark.LoaderParams` class to a higher level so that the connection string is not showing anywhere in the log.

Is there any way that I can do that?

Here's my `log4j.properties` config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=${root.logger}
root.logger=INFO,console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
shell.log.level=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=${shell.log.level}
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer=${shell.log.level}

log4j.logger.jobLogger=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my configuration, I use the following to log the `LoaderParams` statements at `WARN` and everything else from the Kinetica Spark connector at `INFO`:

```
log4j.logger.com.kinetica.spark=INFO
log4j.logger.com.kinetica.spark.LoaderParams=WARN
```

Comment: thanks! yes, I used those configs as well and it works